# How to show a Django auth user field in a custom admin list display

Tags: python, django

I am using the Django auth user model along with a custom user profile model. The user profile admin looks like this:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'first_login', 'project', 'type']
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

The user profile model looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_login = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('R', 'Reader'), ('A', 'Author'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 9, choices = TYP_CHOICES, blank = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I like to do is to display the `is_active` property of the user in the list display of the UserProfileAdmin. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you define say `wrapped_is_active` method in your custom admin model with signature like:

```
def wrapped_is_active(self, item):
    if item:
        return item.user.is_active
wrapped_is_active.boolean = True
```

You should specify that method in your list_display, so that is becomes like:

```
list_display=['user', 'first_login', 'project', 'type', 'wrapped_is_active']
```

for more information see [Django admin site documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: Works :) But why does a lookup not work such as 'user__is_active'?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems like in this case admin builds their view based on `queryset` data. And checks for attribute and if is is callable then call it to get value. May be it is possible to play with `get_queryset` method of admin. But definitely that should be double checked.

Comment: There was a ticket [#5863](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5863) to allow `list_display` to handle attributes on foreign keys like `user__is_active`, but it was closed as "won't fix".

Answer (score 0):

it's possible : I made changes in your code have a look :

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'first_login', 'project', 'type','is_active']
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_login = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('R', 'Reader'), ('A', 'Author'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 9, choices = TYP_CHOICES, blank = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late! but i found a simpler way:

you can add a function in your model UserProfile as like:

```
    def is_active(self):
        return self.user.is_active
```

and you can add in list_display:

```
    list_display = ('user', 'first_login', 'project', 'type', 'is_active')
```